# Conky: why does upspeedgraph look like downspeedgraph when values are different?

Tags: wireless, conky

I wrote my first conky file recently and have been tweaking it. I added an upspeedgraph and downspeedgraph to my network section. But regardless of the actual up and down speeds, the graphs look almost identical most of the time.

That is, my 'up' typically shows 0 to maybe a couple KiB whereas my 'down' oscilates more and wider but the two graphs output about the same most of the time.

Do these graphs even remotely resemble reality?

Is there a way to make my upspeedgraph actually look different based on the actual value of my upspeed? Here is an image of the code next to the graph at the right. You can see that though I use the different graphs and that the up and down values are different, the graph output is about the same.

prtsc of my desktop showing the conky file and the conky output at right, showing the up and down speed graphs are about the same:

[image: screen]

My the network section of my conky code is below:

```
${font Andale Mono-10}${color1}Network${font}
${color3}${voffset -7}${hr}

${color2}${voffset 8}${font}${tab}${tab}${tab}Up: ${alignr}${color4}${upspeed wlan0}${color1}${voffset -12} ${upspeedgraph wlan0 25,150 ADFFE9 FF972E}

${voffset -12}
${color2}${voffset 8}${font}${tab}${tab}${tab}Down:${alignr}${color4}${downspeed wlan0}${color1}${voffset -12} ${downspeedgraph wlan0 25,150 ADFFE9 FF972E}
```

Comment: Sounds almost right in reality: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rN5zI.png it looks like this, only raising if there are actual down/uploads are going.

Comment: Hmmm. I guess that makes sense. They aren't exactly the same, after all, so maybe it just looked oddly similar a while ago. Now that I am looking at it at the moment, there are subtle differences between the two. It is ust weird when my up stays around 2 or so KiB and my Down is hovering around 44 KiB the graphs are very similar. It is almost as if the scale is off. As your link showed, the up is lower than the down though both follow similar oscillation patterns. The thickness of the output of the graphs are about the same.

Comment: Well download something larger just to test, as for example the ubuntu.iso and check if it changes then.

Comment: LOL> I just thought of that. Started streaming some Youtube in HD. Indeed the patterns diverged and the graphs look quite different. Guess it is all working properly after all. I figured the chance was high that I screwed up the code somewhere but it looks fine now.

Comment: While it might seem odd, this is actually porfectly normal. Bear in mind that the TCP protocol (typically used for most network communication) includes “acknowledge” responses for each packet receives - so when traffic is sent in one direction you naturally get responses in the opposite direction.

Answer (score 0):

This is normal unless you give your computer something to down/upload. See for example the graph taken in my machine right now from `gnome-system-monitor`:

[image: screen]

Your script looks as far I can see like it is correct.

Answer (score 0):

After figuring out that my network graphs were actually working properly by doing some experiments, I decided to go ahead and get this conky file working on my other linux laptop. Running the same version of Ubuntu with the XFCE desktop, it just would not load. I checked the version of conky to make sure it was the same on both machines. No problems there. I moved the entire .conky directory from my working laptop to the other one. Still would not load... my file. It would load some of the files (using conky-manager) but not all of them including my file.

So to resolve this (after checking compositing settings and other display related settings) I opened one of the conky files that WAS working properly in gedit and my file in gedit to compare the config details. I ended up having to change several parameters, specifically adding ones of the 'own_window' type. Also note instead of 'override' the type had to be 'dock.' I was getting that annoying refresh issue (or lack thereof) where after a few cycles it all becomes illegible.

**Instead of:**

background yes

alignment top_right

cpu_avg_samples 4

use_xft yes

xftfont Andale Mono-9

update_interval 0.5

total_run_times 0

update_interval_on_battery 10

double_buffer yes

own_window yes

own_window_type override

own_window_transparent

default_bar_size 60 8

gap_y 20

gap_x 20

use_spacer left

pad_percents 3

**I had to change it all to:**

background yes

alignment top_right

cpu_avg_samples 4

use_xft yes

xftfont Andale Mono-9

update_interval 0.5

total_run_times 0

update_interval_on_battery 10

double_buffer yes

no_buffers yes

own_window yes

own_window_type dock

own_window_argb_visual no

own_window_transparent yes

own_window_argb_value 0

own_window_colour 000000

own_window_hints undecorated,below,sticky,skip_taskbar,skip_pager

default_bar_size 60 8

gap_y 20

gap_x 20

use_spacer left

pad_percents 3

This is just a section from my config part of my conkyrc file (I left out the custom color variables stuff). Hope this helps others solve a few common problems. Not sure why the original configuration worked on one laptop and not the other, but I confirmed the NEW configuration works on both laptops.